# Use templateUrl instead of inline template in angular/typescript npm package

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, npm

I have my own NgModule published and installed via npm. Currently the template of the component in the imported module has a inline template. The template got huge (200+ LOC) over time and it would be nice to use the templateUrl instead of inline template in the component.

So instead of this:

```
template: `<h1>My template</h1>`,
```

I want to use this:

```
templateUrl: './my-template.html'
```

All the solutions explained in the folowing post don't work if the module/component is imported via node_modules. https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/06/08/component-relative-paths-in-angular-2.html

I know there are some solutions with gulp packages, that resolve the path and put the template as inline string, but is there any other solution to this?

Edit (add more code examples):

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-component',
    templateUrl: './my-template.html'
})
export class MyComponent {
    constructor() {
    }
}
```

The template is in the same directory as the ts file. It works if I move the directory from node_modules/my-package/my-component and put it anywhere in src/app/.

Comment: can you post more code? (An example of your Component would really suffice)

Comment: Component logic can be empty. It is really just the template url in npm components.
The Component works if you copy the component from the node_modules folder to your src/app without changing a single line.

Comment: well not really , if you're to use a relative path the `module: module.id` has to be set in your @Component decorator, otherwise Angular 2 will be looking for your files at the root level

Comment: I am using webpack. If i use `module: module.id` the application won't start with the error `Error: moduleId should be a string in MyModule`.
And yes you are right, Angular is looking at the root level for the files

Comment: so can you share a short example of your Component? I'ts really hard to come up with any solution if there is no code to see.

Comment: I will edit my answer and add some more code.

Comment: so you say it doesn't work when you try to import the component from node_modules? But it works from anywhere else, right?

Comment: The component is found, it is just the template that's not getting found. It is because of the template beeing searched under localhost:4200/my-template.html.
If I copy the directory to app/src it works as expected.